# Finding the Most Similar Match in a Set

Tags: database, algorithm, search

I have a database of animals, each with many attributes ranging from 0 to 1-- these attributes are things like size, speed, hairiness, etc.  Given an input set of attributes, and weights for each type of attribute, I need to find the "closest" match in the set of animals.  Is there an algorithm that accomplishes this in better than O(n) time?

What I'm specifically trying to do is find suitable textures for "animals" produced by a genetic algorithm in a game, by matching them to animals that already exist.  By "closest," I mean the animal whose weighted sum of attribute differences is minimal.  The database and weights are known at application launch time, so a lot of time can be invested towards preparing the data.

I've found algorithms on string matching and product matching given user preferences, but either I'm not finding what I'm looking for or I'm not understanding how to reapply such concepts to my dilemma.  Perhaps there's something from the world of graph theory to help me out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answer is always a [liger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger).

Comment: @A. Webb: Ooh, a constant time solution.  Thanks for the responses everyone, if there's anything I could do to improve this question (so that others with similar problems may find it), please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could treat the items as points in a high-dimensional space, and insert them all into a BSP-tree, such as a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). To use the attribute-weights, you just need to multiply them by the corresponding coordinate: `(w1*x, w2*y, ...)`

**Preparation:** (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Construction), python code)

```python
def kdtree(point_list, depth=0):

    if not point_list:
        return None

    # Select axis based on depth so that axis cycles through all valid values
    k = len(point_list[0]) # assumes all points have the same dimension
    axis = depth % k

    # Sort point list and choose median as pivot element
    point_list.sort(key=lambda point: point[axis])
    median = len(point_list) // 2 # choose median

    # Create node and construct subtrees
    node = Node()
    node.location = point_list[median]
    node.left_child = kdtree(point_list[:median], depth + 1)
    node.right_child = kdtree(point_list[median + 1:], depth + 1)
    return node
```

**Search:** (from [gist](https://gist.github.com/863301), based on the [wikipedia algorithm](https://gist.github.com/863301))

```python
# method of the Node-class

def closest_point(self, target, point, best=None):
    if target is None:
        return best

    if best is None:
        best = target

    # consider the current node
    if distance(target, point) < distance(best, point):
        best = target

    # search the near branch
    best = self.child_near(point).closest_point(point, best)

    # search the away branch - maybe
    if self.distance_axis(point) < distance(best, point):
        best = self.child_away(point).closest_point(target, point, best)

    return best
```

---

**Read more:**

- [High Dimensional Search and the NN Problem](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/high-dimensional-search-and-the-nn-problem/) (blog article)
- [Closest Point Search in High Dimensions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.9194) by Nene and Nyar.
- [Nearest Neighbor Search in Multidimensional Spaces](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.6858) by Tsaparas

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you!  Diagnosing this as the "nearest neighbor" problem is exactly what I needed, even if k-d trees aren't what I use in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you can spend time arranging your data, you can **sort your animals by score** (in `O(nlogn)` time but done only once) and then apply a **binary search over score** to find the closest match in `O(logn)` time.

If you get your animal list from a SQL database, you can get a sorted list by using the `ASC` or `DESC` keywords in your query.

Comment: This would solve a one-dimensional problem -- single attribute. How do you extend it to solve the `m`-dimensional problem? Finding the closest match in each dimension won't do it in general.

Comment: It is hard to see what the scoring function could be that would allow you to sort only once and search for any number of animals (input attributes). Seems like the scoring function would be based on the animal (input attributes). So, is this a `O(n log n)` solution -- re-score and re-sort for each animal you are looking for -- or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I don't think this can work, since there's no absolute ordering you could impose on the animals for all possible inputs (since there are multiple attributes.)  However, I did wonder if arranging the animals into multiple min/max trees (one for each attribute) could result in something useful...

Comment: @A.Webb As the OP said that there were "attributes and weights for each attribute", I supposed the score of each animal was the sum of its weighted attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly frame this as a maximum weight matching problem, but the lower bound on the complexity of finding the minimal such matching is going to be much, much worse than `O(n)`.  Think more like `O(n^3)`.

If I had to attempt to solve this, I would consider pairwise matching your attributes of the same type according to weight (i.e., create a weighted edge between your input 'hairy' attribute and every other 'hairy' attribute in the data set, using some factor of the input weight and the inverse of the difference between the query 'hairy' value and the matched 'hairy' value).  At that point you can merge all the edges going to a specific animal, and take the sum of the edge weights as the match score.

For example:

```
Monkey:  
A1: 0.5 
B1: 0.25
C1: 1.0

Giraffe:
A2: 0.2
C2: 0.9
D2: 0.1

Input query:
Ai: 0.4 with weight 0.8
Di: 0.2 with weight 0.25
```

So we create the following graph:

```
Ai --> A1 with weight 0.8 * 1/abs(0.5-0.4) (i.e., 8.0)
Ai --> A2 with weight 0.8 * 1/abs(0.2-0.4) (i.e., 4.0)

Di --> D2 with weight 0.25 * 1/abs(0.1-0.2) (i.e., 2.5)
```

Then we collapse all edges with attributes in the same target animal, to get our candidates:

```
Monkey: 8.0
Giraffe: 4.0 + 2.5
```

It's not pretty, and it's worse than `O(n)` (probably by some factor of `m`, where `m` is the number of attributes you are trying to match on), but it might be a starting point from which to start to optimise a better solution.

Comment: True, the worst case is pretty bad, but if there were some way to convert this into a graph traversal, I bet the average case would be nearly constant *if* we started with the generated animal's "parent"'s node (since in a genetic algorithm, a child will generally only deviate from its parent slightly.)  Hmm...

Comment: Actually, generating the relation between input attributes and attributes on animals is precisely O(n*m) in the number of animals.  Collapsing and sorting the generated relation may probably be treated as a small constant factor on top of this.  The trick might be to add your computed similarity scores back into a graph in order to use those links to save repeated recomputations over multiple queries?

Answer (score 0):

How about finding number of linear inversions? So you'd have a linear set of data for 2 animals and you'd want to find out how similar or different they are by kinda sorting them. Complexity is same as that of merge sort. For 'n' animals you'll have nC2 inversions counted.